# Does there always exist a reduction between two NP-hard problems?

Tags: reductions, np-hard

Let $A$ and $B$ be NP-hard problems. For all tuples $(A, B)$ does there exist a polynomial time reduction from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$?

Context: I want to prove some problem is NP-hard. Can I pick any problem in NP-hard to reduce from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A decision problem $L$ is NP-hard when for every problem $H$ in NP, there is a polynomial-time reduction from $H$ to $L$. This is important because it does not necessarily go the other way, you can not say there is a polynomial time reduction from $L$ to $H$. This is because a problem can be NP-Hard and not be in NP. If $A$ and $B$ in your question are both not in NP then there may not be a reduction.

Comment: I think I can see an intuitive reason why my statement is not true. If what I asked were true, then it would imply all NP-hard problems are of equal hardness.

Comment: Yes, and when you consider that the halting problem is NP-Hard, then that does not really work.

Comment: Further question, can I use any NP-complete problem to prove L is NP-hard? ~~ Edit: Nevermind! A NP-complete problem is in NP, so there must exist a polynomial time reduction.